# Getting the index of a specif element in a complex list in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a list of this structure List messages = [ [{body: QGB59WIO57 Confirmed. Your account balance was: M-PESA Account : Ksh0.00 on 11/7/22 at 12:42 PM. Transaction cost, Ksh0.00. Dial *334# now to get your stamped M-Pesa Statement., address: MPESA, timestamp: 1657532523000, status: failed}],
I/flutter ( 4659): [{body: QGB7A3UGAX Confirmed. Your account balance was: M-PESA Account : Ksh0.00 on 11/7/22 at 2:18 PM. Transaction cost, Ksh0.00. Dial *334# now to get your stamped M-Pesa Statement., address: MPESA, timestamp: 1657538312000, status: failed}] ]

I want to get the index of where timestamp is equal to 1657538312000 in this case the ondex of the second element of the list

Answer (score 0):

I didn't fully get the structure but you should be able to do seomthing like

```
var index = messages.indexOf(messages.firstWhere((element) => /*your check here*/ ));
```